# Local sitecore instance SSL certs expired

Tags: sitecore-client, xconnect, certificate

Sorry, this seems more simple than I am making it to be but I am just running into multiple errors after reading and trying multiple articles. So after my initial installation of Sitecore, my certs have expired, I have tried creating just one self-assigned cert and then assigning it to my site app pool, which will allow my site to run even though I still get the site isn't secure and passes it on to the unsafe site, however when I try to get to my local Sitecore tree I can NOT get my login page to load up with these certs. I just get the below error.

```
HTTP Error 403.16 - Forbidden
Your client certificate is either not trusted or is invalid.
```

I don't know if I need to update the `identity server`, `xconnect`, and reg app pool with the new cert and then update all the thumbprints or what I need to really do. None of the articles really hit my points, trying to look for help to have the exact walk-through I need. So unsure about thumbprints and if I need to delete the other expired certs, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow steps below and i hope this resolve your issue :

Step 1 – Create a Self-signed certificate

1. Run Windows Powershell as Administrator
2. Type the follow command, then hit enter

   `New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName mydomain.com -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My`

Step 2 – Use Self-Signed Certificate on IIS

1. Open IIS, expand sites
   [image]
2. Select the Site you want to use Self-Signed certificate, right-click on it then Edit Bindings

[image]

3. In Site Bindings, click Add

[image]

4. In Add Site Binding, choose Type HTTPS and on SSL certificate choose the certificate create in Step 1, and click Ok then Close (Site Bindings window)

[image]

2. Create a password using the following command
   `$sslPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "P@ssw0rd" -Force -AsPlainText`
3. Export the certificate as PFX file using the command below
   `Export-PfxCertificate -Cert cert:\LocalMachine\My\AB34CF46EF6DAAE6FCB69C65F4A9C07710644F3F  -FilePath C:\temp\mydomain.pfx -Password $sslPassword`
4. Navigate to the folder you saved the PFX file and check if it was created. In my case, it was on `C:\temp`

[image]

6. Import Certificat

[image]

Please find the complete post with all the details below :

https://viniciusdeschamps.com.br/sitecore-using-ssl-part-1/

Comment: Would be great to fine-tune this answer with code from this blog post and refer blog post at the end. Sometimes blog does not exist, in that case, this answer will be still relevant

Comment: I want to add that this post helped me with the link provided. I did however run into issues with login so I recreated these steps for my Xconnect and IdentityServer using those names instead of mydomain example and worked great. Thank you for the help.